Ebike for NYC for under $320 Buy or Build?

I commute every day around 8 miles and I want to buy an ebike. I tried out the NYC citibike ebikes and they made me realize that I would bike to work more if I had an ebike - but the citibikes are too expensive to rent. So I have a small budget of $320 to buy an ebike. 
I tried looking on Amazon, but most of the bikes in this range are not allowed to be sold in NYC - because the batteries are not UL-rated, I think. So there aren't really good options to buy online. I wat thinking of buying a conversion kit instead and attaching it to an old bike. But I'm so new to this field.
1] Do you have recommendations for a full ebike at this price?
2] Do you have recommendations for a good conversion kit at this price?
3] Which of the above would you recommend to buy?

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm afraid that product recommendations are off-topic here, since those questions don't age well, or have wide applicability.  You might search here for other questions about e-bike conversions, and see what questions/problems people have had about them.

Be sure to check electrical safety records or reviews, as cheap E-bikes have been said to cause quite a few fires already.

What kind of bike are you riding now?   Perhaps some minor changes there can help?   Decent ebikes cost as much as decent normal bikes, plus more for the battery/motor/etc.  Any ebike that cheap will cut corners on the bike part.

If you buy or build an ebike in your price range, it will be an exercise in frustration. An everyday rider ebike in this price range will not be dependable. You might be able to find a good used ebike in that price range - maybe.

New 18650s from a reliable brand that you can trust not to catch on fire when used properly and are suitable for use in a bicycle are $8-$12 if you're buying anything less than an entire container load.  You need about 30 of them for a basic size bicycle battery.

Do not get a new e bike for less than $800.
Compared to a regular bike, an E bike has a lot of extra complexity and cost that's fairly inevitable. As such, at the low end of price, you will inherently only see bikes that are massive reliability hazards or just fire hazards.
For this price range, I think you're best off getting a good, used bike (and the necessary lights/helmet etc to make it safe to ride in a city).
The other option would be an electric scooter which can be found for a lot cheaper since there is a lot less structure (smaller wheels, less frame, etc) that makes it a lot easier to make a cheap but safe version.
